# B&W Invasion Film where humans are taken over

Tags: story-identification, movie, alien-invasion

Its a 50s B&W film where the aliens come to earth in small meteorites and from memory are like mushrooms/spores and when a human gets close it bursts and takes them over. One scene I remember at the end is the alien somehow forms in a nuclear reactor and get huge and people are trapped in the control room and there is blood coming out of a small access pipe as the alien absorbs humans.

Its been bugging me for days so any help appreciated

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brain_Eaters > not going to put this as an answer because it's parasite rather than spores but could this be it?

Comment: Thanks Carl but I'm just watching Quatermass II (i'm up to episode 3 )and I think its the one. There may well have been another movie similar and I will be watching The Brain Eaters as I love these B&W movies.British ones have the best horror element even with the naive filming...real atmosphere

Comment: There's also this Stack Exchange site if you didn't know it existed...
http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41048/alien-invasion-movie-with-sores-and-blob/41068#41068

Comment: I'll be checking that one out as well.Much appreciated

Comment: @topgazza - So I take it you're watching the original TV serial? Keep in mind that it was also a movie (that's what the trailer I posted was from), so if the TV version matches the plot details but not the visuals you remember, it may be worth checking out the movie too. By the way I also highly recommend the follow-up, Quatermass and the Pit (which was also both a TV serial and a movie).

Comment: Q & The Pit is one of my all time favourites.SciFi and horror combined in a magic combination.I probably remember II as a movie more than the TV series but I am enjoying the TV show and will also watch the movie

Comment: I mean the 1967 Q & The Pit....  scary as hell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be [Quatermass II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatermass_II) from 1957? It features meteorites that release gas and take over the mind of anyone who gets sprayed, and eventually it's revealed there's a giant alien life form living inside a giant pressure dome which you might have misremembered as a nuclear reactor.

The movie was an adaptation of an [earlier TV serial](http://www.screenonline.org.uk/tv/id/441212/) with the same story.

Comment: I think thats it, Quatermass II....brilliant reply. I had a feeling it was a well known title. I can sleep at night now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Invasion of the Body Snatchers ?

> The story depicts an extraterrestrial invasion that begins in the fictional California town of Santa Mira. Alien plant spores have fallen from space and grown into large seed pods, each one capable of reproducing a duplicate replacement copy of each human. As each pod reaches full development, it assimilates the physical characteristics, memories, and personalities of each sleeping person placed near it; these duplicates, however, are devoid of all human emotion. Little by little, a local doctor uncovers this "quiet" invasion and attempts to stop it.<sup>1</sup>

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Body_Snatchers

Comment: Thanks but definately not Body Snatchers.The aliens dont replicate the humans just take them over. I cant remember if they become zombie like or retain their personalities. But the spores burst like seed pods